# Add new rule to Codan

Tags: eclipse-cdt, codan

I am using the integrated CODAN static code analysis tool in Eclipse CDT. But i want to add some rules to check naming conventions of my code. How can I create and add that kind of rules to Codan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add rules to Codan first of all you have to make modification in Plugin.xml file by adding problem and checker tag.

```
    <checker
    class="org.eclipse.cdt.codan.internal.checkers.NamespaceNaming"
    id="org.eclipse.cdt.codan.internal.checkers.NamespaceNaming"
    name="%checker.name.NamespaceNaming">
 <problem
       category="org.eclipse.cdt.codan.core.categories.CodeStyle"
       defaultEnabled="true"
       defaultSeverity="Error"
       description="%problem.description.NamespaceNaming"
       id="org.eclipse.cdt.codan.internal.checkers.NamespaceNaming"
       messagePattern="%problem.messagePattern.NamespaceNaming"
       multiple="true"
       name="%problem.name.NamespaceNaming">
 </problem>
```

Then in bundle.properties you have to add message and description of your problem. After which you have to create a class in Codan Source code, do what implementation you like to do in it (like you can create a pattern with regex so you can compare your file name with it).